# My app crashes on devices running Android version below 9

Tags: android, sdk, crash

I am testing my app in Samsung remote lab and discovering that it keep crashing in devices running on Android below 9.

Searching on Google made me only more confused and aware of how vast is my ignorance.

```
build.cradle:

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.photobangkok.moneytalk"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'
}
```

When I try to lower minSDKversion to 14 I got the below error:

> > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14...

I am showing ads in this app so I need to use adroidx.

Comment: whats the crash log?

Comment: I am not using Android studio emulator and not have a real device running android 7. I use Samsung remote lab